# How to Browse MS Olap cube in Excel NOT using Pivot Table

Tags: olap-cube

Suppose you have a 2 dimensions cube (Units Sold) in MS Olap. Dim 1 is Product and Dim 2 is Country. In the 'Units sold' MS olap cube the cell having the coordinate ('Car', 'France') have a value (says '123'). 
If I set up a Pivot Table in Excel, the cell with reference ('Car', France') may show a complete different number (depending of the filters ... of course). Is there a way to have still the right number ('123') : the ideal is to have both : the filtered and the one ('123') from MS Olap.
Think 'Hide' (discrete items) instead of 'Filter' when you tick/untick items in a filter.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is use one measure to do two things at the same time. Which you can't do straight off the bat. However, there are workarounds.

These are all local to Excel only (not server side) as I'm assuming it's only for you. First solution is obvious, second is better, third and fourth use an extension (fourth is my preferred method as it avoids horrendous MDX code).

**1. Second Pivot Table**

Create a second pivot table. First pivot table filtered by Product, Country and second pivot table by other criteria AND Product, Country. You can link the pivot tables with a slicer to choose different values for Product, Country.

**2. CUBE formulas in Excel sheet cells**

You don't actually need to use pivot tables to access cubes (depending on the implementation).

```
=CUBEVALUE("Sales","[Measures].[Profit]","[Time].[2004]","[All Product].[Beverages]")`
```

These CUBEVALUE formulae are based off the MDX code that goes into the Microsoft Analysis Server implementation. It goes like this:

```
=CUBEVALUE("CUBE NAME","[Measure Group].[Measure]","[Dimension].[Attribute]","[Dimension].[Attribute]")
```

You can add in whatever dimensions/attributes you want then.

**3. Use the OLAP PivotTable Extension.**

This allows you to create your own custom measure for individual pivot tables. Once again, using MDX. I believe you can do a similar thing like with the Cubevalue formulas - i.e. add in whatever dimensions/attributes you want on top of whatever will be filtered.

https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/

**4. DAX Studio**

DAX is the query language that powers PowerPivot. DAX studio allows you to connect to PowerPivot models and run queries - similar to SQL but just using a different language..

DAX studio allows you to connect to OLAP Cubes too. So you can perform queries against a Cube, then export it as a txt file, linked table in excel etc.

https://daxstudio.codeplex.com/

---

If what you'll be doing is basic, you could probably get away with 1 or 2.

However, I do highly suggest you take a look at the OLAP PivotTable Extension anyway. It has a feature which allows you to paste a list of values to filter by - instead of having to manually tick them all.

Saved me hours of woe!

Comment: Very well detailed answer. Many thanks. I will have a deep look on Points 3 and 4.